# Unity 5 - Xbox 360 Controller Input: How to stop camera from dragging?

Tags: unity-game-engine, xbox

So, one of my Xbox Controller's joysticks control my camera movement. But when I stop moving, it drags!
How do I stop this?

Comment: `But when I stop moving, it drags!` I have no clue what you mean by this. Can ou show your code for the movement?

Comment: No, in the Input tab, I set Horizontal and Vertical to work with my Xbox 360 Controller. But it drags. When I stop moving the Joystick, it keeps on moving, but really slowly.